# How to use swiftyJson to get arrayvalue in TableView?

Tags: swift

I use swiftyJson to parse data and, but do not know how to parse array.
Here is code.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var json:JSON = JSON.null
    var urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
    var pokamon = [[String:AnyObject]]()

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pokamon.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        var dict = pokamon[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameLbl.text = dict["name"] as? String
        cell.typesLbl.text = dict["types"]?[0] as? String
        cell.hpLbl.text = dict["hp"] as? String
        cell.subtypeLbl.text = dict["subtype"] as? String

        if let image = URL(string: dict["imageUrl"] as! String){
            let task = urlSession.downloadTask(with: image) { (url, repsponse, error) in
                if error != nil{
                    print("sorry")
                    return
                }
                if let okURL = url{
                    do{
                        let downloadImage = UIImage(data: try Data(contentsOf: okURL))
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            cell.myImage.image = downloadImage
                        }
                    }catch{
                        print("error")
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 224
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myTableView.delegate = self
        myTableView.dataSource = self

        Alamofire.request("https://api.pokemontcg.io/v1/cards").responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in

            if response.result.isSuccess {

                let json:JSON = try! JSON(data: response.data!)
                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)
                if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["cards"].arrayObject{
                    self.pokamon = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                }
                if self.pokamon.count > 0{
                    self.myTableView.reloadData()
                }
            } else {
                print("error: \(response.error)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

From cellForRowAt in tableView, it shows "Ambiguous use of 'subscript'" with below code, have no idea how to solve it. The rest like "name", "hp", and "subtype" are no problem!

```
cell.typesLbl.text = dict["types"]?[0] as? String
```

Could anyone help me with this error?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the json response for that key?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler must know the type of any subscripted object. Tell the compiler that you expect an array of strings.

```
cell.typesLbl.text = (dict["types"] as? [String])?.first
```

---

In Swift 3+ all JSON values are `Any` not AnyObject so declare the array

```
var pokamon = [[String:Any]]()
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `cell.typesLbl.text = (dict["types"] as? [String]).first as? String`

Comment: Right, thanks, and then you can even omit the final type cast.

Comment: If Vadim's answer helps you, you can give an upvote (optional, to encourage the person who gave you an answer, an upvote will also help other people to find the most voted answer) and also mark his answer as correct answer so it will be beneficial to other people who will come to your question in future. @KDerek

Comment: @Hemang could you help me to do it? I am new to come stackoverflow, not familiar how to upvote.

Comment: @KDerek, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) you go.